# "He is in death" or "He is dead" or "He died"? Are they all correct?

Tags: word-usage

> - "*He is in death*"
> - "*He is dead*"
> - "*He died*"

**Are they all correct?**

I am feeling that "*He is in death*" and "*He died*" are not correct.

Comment: All are correct except "he is in death." Death is a state. Why do you think "he died" is incorrect?

Comment: @Usernew. _"He is in love."_ It's not so strange to wonder about _"he is in death"_, quite honestly.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter but "he is in death" is grammatically wrong.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter what MamtaD said +1.

Comment: And if a language learner would be aware of all grammatical rules, they wouldn't be much of learner, would they?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter also read Jay's answer, and you will know why "he is in death" is wrong.

Comment: I think you're missing my point here. A comment like @Usernew's has no value to the learner (@Tom). Even though it does answer the question, it sounds snappy and does not explain why the correct options are correct and why the incorrect option(s) are incorrect.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter It is a **comment**, not an answer. This is one difference between a comment and an answer

Comment: When you ask "are they correct", are you expecting them to mean the same thing? For me, writing or saying something that is *grammatically* correct, but is not what one meant to write or say, would *not* be correct. If you are asking if they mean the same thing, please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: @MamtaD: No, actually, “he is in death” is perfectly grammatically correct. It just doesn’t make much sense. In related news, [colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).

Answer (score 16):

"Die" is a verb. So "He died" is correct.

"Dead" is an adjective. So "He is dead" is correct. Like any adjective, you can also use it to describe a noun as part of a noun phrase, like, "The dead man had a bullet hole in his head."

"Death" is a noun that refers to the act of dying or to dying as a general concept. You can say, "His death was slow and painful", or "The fear of death has plagued humanity since the Fall." But it is not a state of being, so you *cannot* say that someone is "in death" like you can say that someone is "in love" or "in despair".

(The phrase "state of being" may not be the best words for the idea I'm trying to express. If anyone can put it better, feel free to come forward!)

Comment: Although note the pseudo-Biblical quote that "[in the midst of life, we are in death][1]". A very archaic usage. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_vita_in_morte_sumus

Comment: @Patrick - I'd say that's a symbolic usage, not just an archaic one.

Comment: @J.R. I've also seen it in the context of "In death, as in life, [insert some observation or wise-sounding phrase]."

Comment: @J.R. I find myself agreeing with the other comments.  I must conclude that "in death" is correct, technically.  However, it is absolutely not a common way to describe the concept.  In that case, "death" refers to a concept that applies to all of humanity; the opposite of "life".  Usually people just say that a person "experiences death", or that they died, or became dead.  However, when discussing death conceptually, and saying that many people are in the state of being dead (e.g., spiritual death), this phrase may be quite appropriate.

Comment: Let me clarify: It was not my intent to say that it is never meaningful to use the phrase "in death", but rather that, because death is not a state of being, it is not meaningful to say that a person is "in death". It is certainly meaningful to say, for example, "We took no pleasure in the death of our enemies" or "In death, as in life, he looked serene".. But here we are talking about "death the concept", not death as a state that a person could be in. Like you can be happy, and you can experience happiness, and you can seek fulfillment in happiness, but you cannot be "in happiness".

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think that's a poetic usage -- symbolic or metaphorical -- and so the usual rules do not apply. Like "I'm in a New York state of mind" -- might make a good song lyric, but not a guide for conventional usage.

Comment: I agree with Jay, but I'll offer another way to put it. If a person were to be "in death" - it suggests that they are "currently experiencing death". What that means in the physical sense is very unclear. Are they actually "*Dead*", or are they "*Dying*"? Compare to being "in love" - currently experiencing love, which doesn't need a hard line to distinguish the difference between two physical states of being.

Comment: @DoubleDouble: It might even be indirect or metaphorical ("He is in death" = "He is experiencing death" = "Someone close to him died recently and he is in mourning"), but I would *not* rely on people understanding that.

Answer (score 2):

To say one is in death would be to say that one is in the presence of death. There is a Latin phrase using this very construction: Media vita in morte sumus which translates to "In the midst of life we are in death". It's an archaic phrasing sometimes used in funeral services. So in summary: it is perfectly good (if archaic) grammar but it wouldn't be used in the sense you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

"He is in death" sounds strange for most occasions because his life has already finished and doesn't exist in this world anymore.

"He is dead" is suitable when you want to describe his state of being.

"He died" is suitable when you want to describe what he did, willingly or not.